# Can you randomize the triangles of an icosphere?

Tags: modeling

Im really struggeling with getting this triangular structure to work.

[image]

Its like half an icosphere but with randomised vertices.

[image]

I already tried editing the vertices with random-proportional editing and then do a limited dissolve.
But this only works to a limit and gives something like this

[image]

If anyone knows a quicker solution than" do it by hand" id be so glad.

Please halp.

Edit:
Haunt_House`s answer worked perfectly
[image]

Comment: that upper image is really difficult to understand... blurred or out of focus, dark... !

Comment: You can also try using [dyntopo sculpting for this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7532/599) if you want more control (you can paint triangle density)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not at all sure whether it will achieve the desired result since for some reason the image above is so blurry that I can't really see what the goal is, but here's how you can randomize the sphere.

- Create an Icosphere and enter Edit Mode.
- Keep the 3D-cursor in the center and set the pivot point to 3D-cursor
- Use <kbd>A</kbd> to select nothing and then from the select menu choose Random Select.
- Hit <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to enable trackball rotation and slightly move the verts. Since it's rotating around the center, the mesh stays spherical.
- Repeat those steps (deselect, random select, trackball rotation) until everything is random enough.

[image: randomized tris 1]

Another way is to start with a level 1 Icosphere.

- Subdivide it with <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>. Set the fractal value in the Redo panel to about 3. This adds noise.
- <kbd>Space</kbd> "to sphere" <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd>. The <kbd>1</kbd> makes sure it's truly spherical again. You can skip that part but the risk of getting overlapping verts becomes higher.
- Repeat the previous two steps 2 or 3 times.

[image: fractal subdivide]

Comment: One is glad to be of service.

Answer (score 17):

An easy way to get random triangles on any geometry is to start from a highly subdivided object and apply a `Decimate` modifier.

You will get nice regular triangles with the `Collapse` option. Use the `Ratio` to tweak the number of final faces.

[image: Icosphere decimated]

Answer (score 1):

**BMesh Version**

Create an icosphere using bmesh. Each vertex is then randomly rotated some amount from 0 to a maximum angle about a random axis.

[image]
*Result of running script, with from left to right, 3, 4 and 5 degree maximum angles.*

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Matrix
from math import radians
from random import uniform

context = bpy.context
# icosphere parameters, edit to suit.
diameter = 1
subdivisions = 4
max_angle = radians(5) # 5 degrees
bm = bmesh.new()

bmesh.ops.create_icosphere(bm,
       subdivisions=subdivisions, 
       diameter=diameter)

# randomize
for v in bm.verts:
    axis = [uniform(-1, 1) for c in "xyz"]
    rot = Matrix.Rotation(uniform(0, max_angle), 3, axis)
    v.co = rot * v.co

me = bpy.data.meshes.new("RandomIco")
ob = bpy.data.objects.new("RandomIco", me)
bm.to_mesh(me)
context.scene.objects.link(ob)
```

Alternatively rather than create an icosphere, can use in edit mode on any mesh to randomly move the radial from origin to vertex, keeping the distance (radius) same.

*Result of running a 1 degree random move about 10 times on selected vertices of half icosphere*
[image]

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Matrix
from math import radians
from random import uniform

context = bpy.context
ob = context.edit_object
me = ob.data
# randomise parameters

max_angle = radians(1) # 5 degrees
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
# randomize
for v in bm.verts:
    if not v.select:
        continue
    axis = [uniform(-1, 1) for c in "xyz"]
    rot = Matrix.Rotation(uniform(0, max_angle), 3, axis)
    v.co = rot * v.co

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
me.update()
```