# Tesselate a plane

Tags: mesh, modifiers

So I'm looking for an easy way to tessellate a plane in blender, where the centre of the plane has a lot of detail (tris/quads) while the edges have very little with detail being interpolated in between.

Is it possible to do this solely in blender or will I have to write a script to implement it?

Comment: do you mean remesh to triangles ?

Comment: Did you try that with remesh modifier using weight paint as a vertex group?

Comment: @Chebhou & Denis No I haven't tried that

Comment: @Soapy do you want to keep the original points ?

Comment: @Soapy I mean decimate modifier.

Comment: @Denis no but decimate is looking good...

Comment: @Chebhou no, just as long as it stays as a plane

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5136/599

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**You can do that with decimate modifier using vertex group.**

Create a plane, switch to Edit Mode and hit <kbd>W</kbd> button, then from the menu select Subdivide and in operator panel change number of subdivision to 100.

[image]

Switch to Weight Paint Mode, select **Weight Gradient** and start painting from the center out in one stroke.

[image]

Then in Weight Gradient operator panel or by using <kbd>F6</kbd> button change Type to **Radial.**

[image]

Switch back to edit mode, add Decimate Modifier and in Vertex Group name select group that was created by the weight paint.

[image]

Then change the parameters of the modifier to get desired result.

[image]

Comment: Ha, just did this myself, but only thanks to you comments!