# How to apply a modifier to the part of an object?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

How to apply a modifier (for example "subdivision surface"), only to the part of an object, not to a entire object?

Comment: With subdivision surface you cant, some other modifiers can use vertex groups like this http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/29106/tesselate-a-plane/29109

Comment: for subsurf you can use sharp edges